# How to choose "Integrated of order" for time series data?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, unit-root

My data series becomes stationary at 2nd difference but it is also stationary at 1st difference only with inclusion of trend or constant term. So, what Integrated of order should I choose 1 or 2?

Comment: Could you edit to make it more explicit what you mean by "order of integration"?

Comment: Maybe look at the AIC.

Comment: Generally you want to take the smallest difference. Modelling a very high difference (e.g. 3rd or 4th) with an ARIMA model is hard to interpret and can lead to extremely wide confidence intervals for forecasting in my experience.

Comment: Thanks! I also think using integrated of order 1 is better.